# Cannot change directory into a symbolically linked directory

Tags: bash, ubuntu, permissions, file-permissions

I have a directory on my Ubuntu 18.04 server

It's owned by www-data

```
/var/www/html/svg

drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data  20K Apr 16 05:48 svg
```

As the "ubuntu" user, I've created a symbolic link to the directory from /tmp as I need a webservice to access this directory.   This works as expected.

```
pwd
/tmp

lrwxrwxrwx  1 ubuntu   ubuntu     17 Apr 15 09:11 svg -> /var/www/html/svg
```

However, if I'm logged in as any user on the server, and try and cd into the symlinked directory

```
cd /tmp/svg
```

I get the following error:

```
-bash: cd: /tmp/svg: Permission denied
```

And if I cd into the actual directoy /var/www/html/svg as any user, I can do with no problems.

Worryingly, this even happens as root.

What could be causing this?  I want to be able access this symbolic link instead of having to explicitly cd to the directory.

Comment: Is `/var/ww/html/svg` mounted in any way? What are the permissions of `/var` and `/var/www` and `/var/www/html`? What are the permission of `/tmp`?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing symlink ownership to match the working case

```
chown -h www-data:www-data /tmp/svg
```

---

As pointed in the comments, updated answer to pass `-h` flag to avoid link de-referencing.

> **-h, --no-dereference**
>   affect  each  symbolic  link  instead of any referenced file (useful only on systems that can change the ownership of a symlink)

Comment: This would need the -h flag, otherwise it would change the owner of the dir the links points to

Answer (score 1):

You can either change perms of the sym link, eg :

```
chmod -h 777 /tmp/svg
```

Or the owner, to match your actual dir it points to :

```
chown -h www-data:www-data /tmp/svg
```

Comment: chmod -h isn't allowed (the option isn't in my build of chmod)

Comment: And I've run chown -h www-data:www:data /tmp/svg but I still can't cd into it as root